# How can I get Audience Interests from Instagram via API?

Tags: instagram-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'd like to know if there's a way to get instagram audience interests like hypeauditor.com does, via API or something else. I've read the documentation and can't find a way... but maybe some workaround this?

Thank you so much! for your help.